# decrement mysql column values of 22%

Tags: mysql

I have a table of my MySQL database named "jos_hikashop_price" in this table I have a colum for prices "price_value". I need to decrement at one time all the values of the "price_value" column of 22% of it's value

Is it possible with a Query in PHPMYAdmin? If yes could someone please suggest me the code of the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with a query.  Hint:  `UPDATE`.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, could you please give me the entire query I should use? I'm not good writing this...

Comment: @Franceso . . . Basically, you shouldn't be using SQL if you don't know how to write such a basic statement.  A basic tutorial, primer, book, video is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a `UPDATE` query like

```
update jos_hikashop_price
set price_value = price_value - (price_value * 0.22);
```